# How to display alternate text on <p:graphicImage> in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, graphicimage

I'm displaying images on `<p:graphicImage>` which are stored under the `webroot\resources\fileUpload\product_image\thumb` directory as follows.

```
<p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" 
                name="#{not empty row.prodImage?'product_image/thumb/':'&nbsp;'}#{row.prodImage}" 
                alt="#{row.prodName}"/>
```

`row` refers to a JPA entity object stored in a `java.util.List<Entity>` which is retrieved while iterating over a `<p:dataTable>`.

---

When an image name is empty, the `name` attribute of `<p:graphicImage>` is evaluated to  `name=" "`. In which case, it does not work just leaving the page blank without any errors.

If `&nbsp;` in the conditional expression is removed then, it causes `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown.

So, how to display alternate text on `<p:graphicImage>`, if the image to display is unavailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If `&nbsp;` in the conditional expression is removed then, it caused `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown*

Indeed, reproduced it. That's technically a bug in PrimeFaces' `GraphicImageRenderer`. At line 70, it should have done a `if(name != null && !name.isEmpty())` instead of alone `name != null` before trying to get it as a resource.

I'm not sure if it's for them worth to fix it as it actually doesn't make sense to specify an empty `name` and the workaround is relatively easy by conditionally rendering two images, one without the name and another with the name:

```
<p:graphicImage alt="#{row.prodName}" rendered="#{empty row.prodImage}" />
<p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" name="product_image/thumb/#{row.prodImage}" alt="#{row.prodName}" rendered="#{not empty row.prodImage}" />
```